# How to find the current uiviewcontroller?

Tags: iphone

My Application has around 4 UIViewControllers. Is it possible to find the current UIViewController?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NSArray *viewContrlls=[[self navigationController] viewControllers];
[viewContrlls lastObject];
```